# WebScraping loading page redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm friendly scraping a supermarket website. 
When I go for the first time at the URL I have to set the location and chose the supermarket I want, and if I use its URL I don't have to set the location each time I use it.

After that I'm scraping all the pages href.

The problem is when I use URLs from the pages href it's each time redirect me to the select your location page...

Does there is a way to don't be redirected to the "get your location" page at the begining  and keep the location setted ?

I'm using NodeJS and `request` to load the html code and `cheerio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cheerio` is a simple but powerful scraping tool. Unfortunately, there are a few things that it can't do that a browser can. It's hard to tell exactly what's happening without a link to the page, but I'm guessing it's one of two things:

1. The site uses cookies to save your location setting, in which case you need to configure `cheerio` to use cookies. I haven't tried this, but here's an article that covers some of this: https://www.webniraj.com/2015/03/16/nodejs-scraping-websites-using-request-and-cheerio/
2. The page relies on asynchronous javascript, such as ajax. This is the case with JS based web-apps like facebook. Unfortunately, unless they implement server-side rendering, the only solution here is to use a browser to fetch the page, as you have to wait for it to load properly. There are a variety of 'headless' browser you can use for this, such as PhantomJS, casper, zombie (I think), and a few others. I've used Phantom, and it's a bit complicated, but it does a good job.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks I've founded the answer on the article you gave me. I have to set defauts option for request to save cookies.